# Keys Collection of Find Method is coming out null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datarow

When I debug after clicking the Update Button on the browser, it throws a NullReferenceException on the below line in `GridView1_RowUpdating`:

```
dr["Phone Number"] = e.NewValues["Phone Number"];
```

Full code:

```
public partial class DataBound : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    private void getCacheData()
    {
        if (Cache["DATASET"] != null)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = Cache["DATASET"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private void getDataDB()
    {
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("select `Customer ID`,`Customer Name`,`Phone Number` from customer", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "Customer");
        ds.Tables["Customer"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables["Customer"].Columns["Customer ID"] };
        Cache.Insert("DATASET", ds, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        getCacheData();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = (DataSet)Cache["DATASET"];
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Customer"].Rows.Find(e.Keys["Customer ID"]);
            dr["Phone Number"] = e.NewValues["Phone Number"];
            dr["Customer Name"] = e.NewValues["Customer Name"];
            Cache.Insert("DATASET", ds, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            getCacheData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        getCacheData();
    }

    protected void btnGetDataDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getDataDB();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that dr is null, I debugged the code..but don't know why its coming null when I'm writing like this                                                 DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Customer"].Rows.Find(e.Keys["Customer ID"]);

Comment: Yes checked that too, but I've "Customer ID" as my Primary key, don't know why its null here inside GridView1_RowUpdating                                                     ds.Tables["Customer"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables["Customer"].Columns["Customer ID"] };

Comment: Tried DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Customer"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().FirstOrDefault(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Customer ID"]).Equals(e.Keys["Customer ID"]));  this line is not the problem....actual problem is e.Keys("Customer ID") is coming out null....I've checked 100 times...Key name is correct but no idea why it is not able to find the key name

Comment: e.Keys["Customer ID"] returns a null value...IF I check         ds.Tables["Customer"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables["Customer"].Columns["Customer ID"] };
 it actually marks the "Customer ID" as primary key but returnning null when I write e.Keys["Customer ID"]

Comment: When I debug Code Line : ds.Tables["Customer"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables["Customer"].Columns["Customer ID"] };   has value    Value:  {System.Data.DataColumn[1]}.....that means DataColumn1  that is "Customer ID" is being set as Primary Key.let me check this more ...Thank You